# I'm saving debug logs for iTerm2 but why can't I find them?

Tags: terminal, crash, performance, python, iterm

[image: Bash debug log]

I can't find the file `/tmp/debuglog.txt` anywhere using finder.

`locate debuglog.txt` failed because there is no database, so I've built one using `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist`

Database complete, `locate debuglog.txt` returns nothing.

**Question:** I'm saving debug logs for Bash but why can't I find them?

---

#### Background

I start Anaconda Python 3.7.6 and run scripts from iTerm2 using macOS 10.15.7.

A few times a week iTerm2 suddenly freezes, and I have to use Quit from the application and start it again.

- I loose some of the "backarrow history" which is troublesome for me.
- I also worry about potential security issues.

I use matplotlib 3.1.3 all the time and I know there are some issues. So far I can't *exclude* it from the list of possible causes.

From [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/9145) I have found [this explanation](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/wikis/DebugLogging) how to start a log, then I have to wait until the bug happens again then toggle it again to save some log.

I have supposedly captured an issue many times in hopes of collecting many debug logs. I can not find `/tmp/debuglog.txt` anywhere though.

Comment: Have you looked using terminal and a simple ls

Comment: @mmmmmm That's a great idea since (I assume) it's the application that is freezing not Python itself! I will start using terminal (as opposed to iTerm2) now and see what happens for the next few days. But I'm not sure what "a simple ls" means.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps that message is from a time where the temporary directory was indeed `/tmp` many macOS versions ago. Nowadays macOS manages a private temporary directory per GUI user which is provided as the environment variable `$TMPDIR` somewhere in `/var/folders` — try `open $TMPDIR/debuglog.txt`.

Comment: *Thanks for your speedy reply!* Outside of Python I'm not much of a Bash user, and while I am confident your answer is helpful I don't know how to check this, nor what an environment variable is. However there is a weekly Python meeting and I can sit with a bunch of developers who will likely know exactly what to do. I'll update here as soon as that happens.

Comment: @uhoh Edited end of answer with full command, you can give paths to `open`.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I haven't had a freeze in the last few hours, but I've toggled on and off a few times and restarted iTerm2 and to `open $TMPDIR/debuglog.txt1` it always gives me the same reply with the exact same file name: `The file /var/folders/td/2rxc88zx59gd3ym2d4_47t480000gn/T//debuglog.txt does not exist.` I know that my primary goal personally should be to figure out how to stop python (probably matplotlib) from causing the freeze, but I think that anything that can freeze iTerm2 should be tracked down and reported. Apparently this naughty problem can prevent debug logging!

Comment: what toggling means: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxtm5.png per [this comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/404987/im-saving-debug-logs-for-bash-but-why-cant-i-find-them#comment571726_404987) I will try Terminal to see if it also freezes.

Answer (score 1):

According to the wiki at
https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/wikis/DebugLogging
If you go to menu at top and select Iterm2>Toggle Debugging,
it will start the debugging session, if you click it again,
it will turn off debugging, and then the file will be written
to /tmp/debuglog.txt.
I just tried it and it works for me

Comment: okay all that happens for me too, and if I then type `cd /tmp` and `ls *debug*` I see it and `nano debuglog.txt` opens it and I see a big huge mess generated for software developers rather than the two lines I typed in debug mode. Also, I don't know how to locate `/tmp` in Finder - is it invisible? If I search my computer for "debuglog" it does not show up in results either.

Comment: it is not hidden, I went to terminal and typed 

$cd /tmp

$open .

and that opens the folder in finder
for some wierd reason it opens to
/private/tmp
but you will find the file there

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason for not finding the debug log is that iTerm does not have full disk access. It asks once when first installed, but if you skip giving it the permission, many things still work but it is unable to write to `/tmp`. Go to System Settings, Privacy & Security, Full Disk Access, and make sure iTerm's access is enabled. You may need to restart iTerm for it to receive the access.